# Invalid expression term string

Tags: c#, if-statement, compiler-errors

I'm trying to get

```
 Console.WriteLine("Please enter a day of the week, e.g. Tue: ");
 today =  Console.ReadLine();
 GotoWork = string (today != SUN && today != SAT) ?

              Console.WriteLine("You have to go to work today...") ; 
              Console.WriteLine("Ahh... the weekend. No work!");'
```

to compile and tell me if I need to go to work, but it tells me that '(today != SUN && today != SAT)' is an

```
invalid expression term for string.
```

Comment: Change `SUN` to `"SUN"`, the same with `SAT` and read a bit more about C# syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap in double quotes `SUN` and `SAT` since this is how strings are represented.

```
today != "SUN" && today != "SAT"
```